# How to fix Empty Space on top of Curved Android Phone

Tags: android, react-native

My react-native app look totally fine on most Android devices (and iOS) I tested on emulator, but some devices with noticeable curved screen on top (Google Pixel 4, API 29), it shows a big empty region on top of the phone.

This does not look normal. Do you know how to fix it ?

[image]

[image]

I am using `SafeAreaView` but without any Android specific padding/margin.

```
<SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
    ... My App Code come here.
</SafeAreaView>
```

I also tried to remove the the `SafeAreaView` and used regular `View` instead but it still wont go away.

Just for testing I removed everything and added a hello world test screen.
It still gives same wide empty space.

My App.js:

```
export default class Main extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super (props);
    }

  render () {
    return (
        <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
            <Text> Hello World, How to fix this ? </Text>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => Main);
```

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't remove it, it's a display bug on the Pixel 4 emulator. A physical Pixel 4 doesn't have that gap.

See my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68178200/1437016) for a detailed explanation.

[image: Real one vs emulator]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this simply by hiding your **`StatusBar`** just like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { StatusBar, View, Text } from "react-native";

export default class Main extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        StatusBar.setHidden(true);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
                <Text> Hello World, How to fix this ? </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

**Update:** set `StatusBar`'s `transluent` attribute to true along with make its' background as `transparent` like this:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StatusBar, View, Text } from "react-native";

export default class Main extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    StatusBar.setTranslucent(true);
    StatusBar.setBackgroundColor("transparent");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
        <Text> Hello World, How to fix this ? </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried this, but with StatusBar hidden, it gives an empty black region of exact same broad size (instead of broad statusbar)

Comment: @kernelman, is this showing on real devices or only emulators?

Comment: i tried setTranslucent() & setBackgroundColor() as you mentioned, but it makes that broad area "white" (the background color of the app). It doesnt make that broad area go away.

Comment: And I've found this issue on emulator. I do not have Pixel4 phone to try it on real device.

Comment: I don't want to make the status bar transparent, I want it to have a color while not being so tall as OP screenshot. Same, only on Emulator don't have Pixel 4 to check.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using this way

```
<StatusBar translucent={true} hidden={true} /> {/* <--- Here */}
```

Comment: @Nooruddin Lakhani, it shows up like this: https://i.imgur.com/BbsmuGN.png

I found that,instead of this we can change the background color to make it look normal but still we can't get rid of the unnecessary padding.

Answer (score 0):

Check statusbar component where you can draw an app under the status bar by using the property named `translucent`. [Reference link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar#translucent)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by going to AVD Manager -> Click on Wipe Data

[Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psKGi.png)