# How do I change the Grey top banner in Android / React Native?

Tags: android, react-native

[image]

Please notice that there is a mid-GREY banner above the app. How can I

1. Remove this (the app should ideally begin right below 9:56)
2. Change the background color (less ideal)

Comment: Could you post some code? To check which component are you using.

Comment: Any feedback would be appreciated, I digged this for hours to find out what specifically happens here!

Answer (score 8):

### TLDR;

It's a display bug on the Pixel 4 emulator. Real Pixel 4 doesn't have that gap.

---

### Edit

My answer below was not spot on. I tried on an emulated Pixel 4, API 29 (with Android Studio 4.2, macOS Big Sur) with rounded corners, as yours, and it rather seems to be an issue with the curve of the phone than an empty `ActionBar`.

#### My app on a pixel 4:

[image: With rounded corners]

#### Even Youtube has this space:

[image: Even youtube]

### Edit 2

#### Compared with [a real Pixel 4](https://youtu.be/mfbSqTB74xM?t=626)

[image: Compared with real one]

We clearly see that this gigantic gap is only on the emulator.
That's a bug on the emulator, and probably the main reason why no one talks about it around the web (googling *Pixel 4 status bar height* shows angry Pixel 5 owners results about its huge height).

Didn't found any bug report about it, I'll file one.

---

### Old answer

What you see is probably an empty [`ActionBar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar), that has the same color of your `StatusBar`.

If you use the default theme, [your app will use it](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up) :

> Beginning with Android 3.0 (API level 11), all activities that use the default theme have an ActionBar as an app bar.

It displays your Application's name, defined in your `MainApplication`'s `android:label` on your *AndroidManifest.xml* (or `MainActivity`'s if not found). As it's empty, there's just an empty space displayed.

As you manage your own navbar, you can disable with the base theme of your choice `Theme.AppCompat.*.NoActionBar`, on *values/styles.xml*:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- You can set the color of your status bar here, or with RN - see further on the answer -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/dark</item>
</style>
```

Don't forget to apply this theme to your `MainApplication`, in your *AndroidManifest.xml*:

```
<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
  ...
```

To illustrate better, here's what it looks like:

#### With the `NoActionBar` (code above)

[image: New config]

#### With `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"` and `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/dark</item>`

[image: With name and light]

#### With `parent="Theme.AppCompat"`, and an empty app name.

[image: With empty app name]

---

For the second part of your question, you can either change the color of your status bar here ([see the docs for this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes)), or [within React Native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar).

Answer (score 2):

go to

`android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xmlandroid/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`

and add this code. it will remove

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:textColor">
            #000000
        </item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: That is not the ActionBar's fault. I can't see how your answer is relevant, could you elaborate?